# Hibernate join without createQuery()

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria, projection

How can I achieve this

```
session
    .createQuery(
        "select person from Pet pet " +
        "inner join pet.person person " +
        "where person.age = 32)
    .list();
```

by, instead of using HQL, use Hibernate functions such as createCriteria(), createAlias(), setProjection(), etc?

Comment: Does `Person` have a relation to `Pet`?

Comment: No that is my main problem I think. There is no mapping from Person -> Pet, only Pet -> Person.

Comment: And the query should return all persons aged 32 who have a pet related to them?

Comment: Exactly, like the given HQL does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
crit.createAlias("pet", "pet");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("age", 32);
crit.list();
```

`createAlias` is used only to inner join with `Pet`, if the point is to list all persons aged 32 which have a pet.

**EDIT** After comments about the model and requirements, try this. Not pretty, but it should work

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Person.class, "person");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("age", 32));
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Pet.class, "pet");
dc.add(Property.forName("pet.person_id").eqProperty("person.id"));
c.add(Subqueries.exists(dc.setProjection(Projections.id())));
List<Person> persons = c.list();
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, since Person doesn't know it has a Pet, only Pet knows it has a Person.

Comment: I've edited my answer, hopefully this new code should work.